# Is there any way to identify and recognize chords in scores using Muse, Finale, Sibelius?

Tags: chords, software

Is there any way to identify and recognize chords in scores using Muse, Finale, Sibelius and other software. Want to select chord in piano score and get a chord definition, its name like Am6-7 or C#dim.

Answer (score 1):

In Finale, select the Chord Tool. Open the Chord menu and select `Two-staff analysis` (or whichever you need), then click on the chord. The result will appear above the staff. Make sure that the piece is in the right key because different chords can have the same notes in them (Am7 and C6) and Finale does some harmonic analysis.

Answer (score 1):

In Sibelius, this is an inbuilt function. Highlight the set of notes, and the chord is displayed in the status bar:

[image: Sibelius Chord Name]

Note that this works on sets of simultaneous notes. If you select a phrase it will display the first chord. For example, if I select the first two bars, it will display `Eb`, rather than any of the subsequent chords.

---

If you want to add chord symbols to an existing score, there is an inbuilt plugin for that:

`Text` > `Plugins` > `Add Chord Symbols`

[image]

Results:

[image: Added chord symbols]

Fifteen internet bonus points if you can figure out the instrumentation. Also, whilst we're here, shoutout to the 'Add Capo Chord Symbols' plugin. Very handy if you want to keep guitarists happy.